# How to get rid of Checkstyle error "unused @throws tag.."

Tags: java, checkstyle

While documenting a method in my java class, I have mentioned an exception in @throws tag, but I am not actually throwing it, but know that the web service I am invoking might throw it. But checkstyle crips about it saying "Unused @throws tag for 'IllegalInputException'"

I have suppressions.xml file, that lists couple of supressions, but I am not able to find out how to get rid of the above mentioned one.

...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Bad, it was missing that in my method signatures. I searched entire web for check style tags, but it was a problem with signatures